# Getting device compliance from Falcon API crowdstrike

Tags: curl

I am learning how to use the falcon api to check device security posture. So far I've learned how to run the oauth2 request to get a bearer token:

```
$ crowdstrike_bearer_token=$(curl -X POST "https://api.us-2.crowdstrike.com/oauth2/token" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=$falcon_api_client_id&client_secret=falcon_api_client_secret")
```

I'd like to find a request to return a list of all of the devices in the crowdstrike subscription. It looks like there is a request for getting devices by their ids.

```
curl 'https://falcon.us-2.crowdstrike.com/api2/devices/entities/devices/v1?ids={device_id}'
```

I added an api client id and key. When I try

```
curl -X GET  "https://api.crowdstrike.com/devices/queries/devices/v1?filter=platform_name:'Windows'" -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer $falcon_api_client_secret'
```

I get

```
{
 "meta": {
  "query_time": 0.001299989,
  "powered_by": "crowdstrike-api-gateway",
  "trace_id": "f25fde53-ec33-4143-ba79-8afefa6a5e82"
 },
 "errors": [
  {
   "code": 403,
   "message": "access denied, authorization failed"
  }
 ]
}
```

but I'd really like to find a request to get the full list of hosts for a crowdstrike subscription. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in $crowdstrike_bearer_token rather than $falcon_api_client_secret to your calls to devices/queries/devices/v1 - you're meant to pass your client ID & key to /oauth2/token, get back a token, then pass that token into subsequent calls